# Why is my ajax call (which return json) doesn't get the decimal property?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

i have an ajax call which is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ Name: 'foo', Price: 5.0 }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { alert(data); }
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Here is my viewmodel.

```
    public class ProductViewModel
{
    [Required, StringLength(60)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, Range(0, 100000)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

When i send the call... only the 'foo' is populated in the viewmodel P but not the price.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(ProductViewModel p)
    {

        var rslt = "success";
        return Json(rslt);
    }
```

I am using the

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting stuff i found here http://digitalbush.com/2011/04/24/asp-net-mvc3-json-decimal-binding-woes/comment-page-1/#comment-3356.

It look like that if you don't add any decimal values such in:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Name: 'foo', Price: 5.0 })
```

It will be considered a integer by the default binder. If you use 5.35 as an example it will work. The solution is provided in the link. You just have to use a DecimalModelBinder that will fix this issue with decimal values.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
[Required, Range(0.0, 100000.0)]
```

Comment: This is a validator, unfortunally that has nothing to do with the problem i am having sorry.

Comment: Have you even bothered to try this solution?  You can lead a horse to water. but you can't make it drink!

Comment: I tried don't worry. :) but as i said the problem was nothing to do with validation and i was pretty sure about that. The problem was a bug in the default modelbinder which was seeing decimal as int.